# equivalent formulation of axiom of choice (Analysis 1 by Tao)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

> (Analysis 1 by Tao) Exercise 8.4.1. Show that the axiom of choice implies Proposition 8.4.7. (Hint: consider the sets $Y_x : = \{ y\in Y : P(x, y) \text{is true}\}$ for each $x \in X$.) Conversely, show that if Proposition 8.4.7 is true, then the axiom of choice is also true.
>
> Proposition 8.4.7. Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, and let $P(x,y)$ be a property pertaining to an object $x \in X$ to an object $y \in Y$ such that for every $x \in X$ there is at least one $y \in Y$ such that $P(x,y)$ is true. Then there exists a function $f: X \to Y$ such that $P(x, f(x))$ is true for all $x \in X$.
>
> Axiom 8.1 (Choice) : Let $I$ be a set, and for each $\alpha \in I$, let $X_\alpha$ be a non-empty set. Then $\prod_{\alpha \in I} X_\alpha$ is also non-empty. In other words, there exists a function $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in I}$ which assigns to each $\alpha \in I$ an element $x_\alpha \in X_{\alpha}$.

My understanding of the axiom of choice is that we are able to pick an arbitrary element form a non-empty set.

But, how does this and the hint given help us solve this question? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "the axiom of choice is that we are able to" simultaneously "pick an arbitrary element from" each set in an arbitrary collection of nonempty sets.

Comment: We know for each $x\in X,$ $Y_x$ is nonempty. So let $(y_x)_{x\in X}$ be the choice function given by AC. It is exactly the $f$ you need for 8.4.7.

Comment: Did you try to play with the various axioms of set theory to make each $P(x,\cdot)$ into a set?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know the replacement Axiom, which says that for each $x \in X$, there exists at most one $y$ for which $P(x,y)$ is true, and there exists a set $\{y : P(x, y) \text{is true for} x \in X \} $.

Comment: You're almost there. Just apply the power set and separation again to get the family of sets you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Since $I_x:=\{y\in Y:P(x,y)\}\neq\emptyset$ for each $x\in X$ the axiom of choice gaurantees there exists a function $f:X\to\bigcup_{x\in X} I_x$ satisfying $f(x)\in I_x$ for each $x\in X$ and therefore $P(x,f(x))$.